# Does magnitude of a charge influence magnitude of force that individual charge exerts on another charge

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electricity, charge

[image: Here's the image for the problem]

two point charges, q1 and q2, are placed 0.3m apart on the x-axis, as shown in the figure above. Charge q1 has a value of -3 nano Coulomb and q2 has a value of +4.8 x10^-8 C. The net electric field at point P is 0.

Given that q2>q1, can it be said that q2 exerts a greater attractive electrostatic force on q1 as the magnitude of q2's charge is greater than the magnitude of q1's charge? Or is it that the attractive force they exert on each other is equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnitude of the forces $q_1$ and $q_2$ exert on each other is equal.  According to [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law), the magnitude of the force that a charge $q_1$ will experience due to a charge $q_2$ is

$$|\mathbf F_{12}|=k_e{|q_1q_2|\over r^2}\ ,$$

where $k_e$ is Coulomb's constant and $r$ is the distance between the charges. But that equation is symmetrical in $q_1$ and $q_2$.  I.e., if you calculate

$$|\mathbf F_{21}|=k_e{|q_2q_1|\over r^2}\ ,$$

you get the same numeric value, because $q_{1}q_{2}=q_{2}q_{1}$.